# Cron stuck because update module

Tags: updating, cron

My cron is stuck because "Drupal core update status :   No update data available", when disable update module, cron run good again.

Just try manual update but it run more than 3 minutes then nothing happen. I'm already clean cache_update and seasson table in database.

Go to /admin/reports/updates/list, all css on page gone and report Last checked: 0 sec ago.

[image: Update page]

I'm running Drupal 6. Please help/

Comment: What do the logs report when your run cron? More importantly, Drupal 6 end of life is right around the corner. https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol